# Why is there a difference between display colors for R.color.<colorString> and Color.parseColor(colorString in hex) in android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-color

Two different ways of setting color codes for android view returning different results, not sure why?

Trying to restructure code and wanted to convert the following snippet:
Method 1:

```
Paint p = new Paint ();
p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
```

to little formatted way of getting result by using color.xml in android

Method 2:

```
Paint p = new Paint ();
p.setColor(R.color.recyclerViewAnimationBackground);
```

[Color Name and display in colors.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9TeO.png)

The problem is the results returned by both should be same, but not sure why they are different.

Method 1: Returns Red
Method 2: Returns Violet

I am not blocked in development effort but hope to get some help in understanding the logic behind this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.color.XYZ` is the *resource identifier* (an `int`, really) that identifies the color resources.

`Color.parseColor("#D32F2F")` actually returns a `Color`.

The latter is what you want. The `R.color` value can only be used where a color *resource* is referenced.

The android support library contains the following code to obtain a color for a resource identifier:

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorResourceId);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
R.color.recyclerViewAnimationBackground
```

gives you the resources id that is from by R.java.

```
Color.parseColor("#D32F2F")
```

give you the correct value not the any id (from R.java).

Use

```
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorResourceId);
```

Comment: :-) I love the fact that we added the support library code at the same time, really

Comment: Love the fact you both added it wrong - completely missed the point of having a ContextCompat class.

Comment: @Amit : Thanks a lot, it helps :)